# Are there diodes which can switch at multiple GHz speed?

Tags: rf-electronics

Are there diodes which can switch at multiple GHz speed? Most of them are limited up to few hundreds of MHz.

Comment: Yes. - - - - - -

Comment: You may want to expand on your question a bit, otherwise this is just a "yes or no" question that isn't very useful to anyone

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not here for shopping requests. If you're not asking about where to buy them, but about how they work, or how they're used in a specific application, please [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for Schottky diodes.

Answer (score 1):

Ultra low capacitance diodes <1pF are capable of operating at GHz frequencies. They are low loss Schottky types.  BAS69xxx from STMicro is one example.